# sql raise_salary procedure

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to make a pl/sql program that will raise the salary of the managers from a table and if the salary is greater then 3000 than I have to set it at 3000 but I don't seem to manage to make that. I have to use o procedure and then to call it from the anonymous block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the anonymous block, you are calling the procedure for every manager. In the procedure, you are raising every manager's pay by 500. By the time the block exits, your managers are going to be getting quite a substantial raise!

Step one is to decide if you want to do the per manager looping in the block or in the procedure. Step two is if you want to raise an exception if a manager is earning > 3000, then you must check to see if the manager is earning > 3000. You check for NULL, but that is it. No, the check in the exception handler doesn't count. The salary had to be NULL for you to get there.

In this example, I've elected to do all the looping in the procedure. All it needs to know is which job type gets the raise and the amount of the raise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Raise_Sal( Target_Job emp.JOB%TYPE, Amount NUMBER ) AS
    Max_Sal       Constant Number := 3000; -- Could also be passed in
    Sal_Null      Exception;
    Sal_Too_Big   Exception;
    pragma exception_init( Sal_Null, -20101 );
    pragma exception_init( Sal_Too_Big, -20102 );

    CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT  ID, Sal
        FROM    Emp
        WHERE   JOB = Target_Job
        FOR UPDATE OF Sal; -- NOWAIT is redundant for cursors
BEGIN
    FOR Emp IN C1 Loop BEGIN
       IF Emp.Sal IS NULL THEN
          Raise_Application_Error( -20101, 'Salary is missing' );
       Elsif Emp.Sal > Max_Sal THEN
          Raise Sal_Too_High;
       Else
          UPDATE Emp SET Sal = Curr_Sal + Amount WHERE CURRENT OF C1;
       End If;
    END;
    Exception
        WHEN Sal_Too_Big THEN
            UPDATE Emp SET Sal = Max_Sal WHERE CURRENT OF C1;
        WHEN Others THEN
            Raise;
    END loop;
END Raise_Sal;
/

DECLARE
  V_Amount Constant Number := 500;
BEGIN
    raise_sal( 'MANAGER', V_Amount );
end;
/
```

This is NOT production-quality code. For one thing, I'd pass in the maximum salary amount so the procedure could be used for "SalesClerk" or "VicePresident" or "SQLDeveloper" or what have you. I'm sure each of those has a different maximum. But you seem to be only interested in learning technique, so take it as just an example.

Also, Gordon's answer points out a problem you may still be missing. You are checking if the salary is greater than the maximum *before* you raise the salary. What if it ends up being greater than the maximum after the update?

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic `update` is:

```
UPDATE emp
    SET sal = (case when curr_sal + amount > 3000 then 3000
                    else curr_sal + amount
               end)
    WHERE job = 'MANAGER' ;
```

I'm not sure how this fits into your procedure, which seems overly complicated.

Comment: I have to make that restriction of 3000 into a exception

Comment: @KatyPiu . . . Seems quite unnecessarily complicated.  If this is for a school assignment, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: it's not a school assignment but I want to do the code like this..I already made it how you suggested but I understood that i can make it with exception and all that and I wanted to see how it looks.